# Office Titus Classification Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ms-office, outlook-addin

Titus Classification is a third-party system for classifying emails.

I need to classify some emails before sending them out using PowerShell. I know how to create and edit emails using PowerShell’s com Outlook.Application.

I just don’t know how to classify the email.

If anyone knows how to  do it in any Microsoft Office product, it will probably work in outlook as well.

```
$outlook = New-Object -com Outlook.Application
$email = $outlook.CreateItem(0)
...Set Classification 
 $email.send()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. All you need to do is add and set a user property in the mail object. Note that if you have issues knowing what to set, just draft up an email and copy the settings.

Comment: Can you show an example? what properties/settings did you use?

Comment: Samples about It?

Comment: I work for a new company and don't have access to that code or Titus Classification.